# making the size of all the buttons same when using @html.Actionlink

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net, flexbox

I have the following four buttons on my web page. One of the button is `@Html.ActionLink`, the shape of this button is thicker than other buttons. I tried to use the same class for `@Html.ActionLink` as for other buttons. below is the screen shot of the buttons:

[image]

below is the code and style sheet for the buttons:

```html
  <div class="form-group buttons-flex" style="margin-top:20px">
            
            <a style="float: left; margin-bottom:20px" href="/PDF/Index" class="Button btn btn-primary">Back to Main Page</a>
    
            <input style="float: right; margin-bottom:20px" type="submit" name="submitButton" id="myBtn1" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary" />
            @Html.ActionLink("Download", "DownloadFile","Statement", null, new { @class = "btn btn-primary" });
            <a style="float: left; margin-bottom:20px" href="/FileUpload/Index" class="btn btn-primary">Upload Signed files</a>
        </div>
```

stylesheet:

```
.buttons-flex {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

How can I make "Download" button same size as other buttons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the only different thing between the buttons is that ActionLink doesn't have the margin. Add this to the ActionLink:

```
@style="margin-bottom:20px;"
```

Or add it to a new class or `btn-primary` class